# Matlab: finding largest sum of first dimension, grouping by second dimension

Tags: matlab

I have a 2-D matrix `A(value, label)`. I want to find the label that has the largest and second largest sum of values. For example:

```
A = (1, 1;
     2, 1;
     3, 2;
     4, 2;
     5, 3)
```

In this case the result should be largest = 2, second largest = 3. How can I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2):

```
[b,m,n]=unique(a(:,2));
[val, idx]= sort(accumarray(n,a(:,1)),'descend');
b(idx(1:2))
```

Output is:

```
ans =

 2
 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
A = [1, 1; 
2, 1; 
3, 2; 
4, 2; 
5, 3];

labels = unique(A(:,2)); % Pull out unique labels

for i = 1:numel(labels)
  idx = (A(:,2) == labels(i)); % Find elements which match current label
  s(i,1) = sum(A(idx,1)); % Sum them
end

r = sortrows([s labels], -1); % Sort by decreasing sum

r(1,2); % Label corresponding to largest sum
r(2,2); % Label corresponding to second largest sum
```

**EDIT** `accumarray` is a built-in function that will do this for you. Although I find the documentation on it somewhat cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question isn't super clear and i don't get what sum you are referring to I'm just gonna guess that you are aiming for something like this

```
q=sortrows(A,-1);
q=q(1:2,:);
```

which will give the two labels (right column) with the largest values (left column) in q.

If this wasn't what you were looking for please comment.

**EDIT:** Missread which column that contained labels, corrected